# while loop is not working upon selecting multiple colums from a table

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop

i have a table with 5 columns like `TABLE(a,b,c,d,e)`.

now i want to select all the columns from `TABLE`.but the script is not workling once the while loop starts.
my php code is:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/db.inc.php' ;
$sql="select * from TABLE";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql );
if (!$result)
{
include_once "wall.html.php";
echo'<tr><td align="center"> OOOOPPPPPSSS!!!SORRY,UNABLE TO DISPLAY LATEST 25 TOPICS</td></tr>';
exit();
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$as[]=$row['a'];
$bs[]=$row['b'];
$cs[]=$row['c'];
$ds[]=$row['d'];
$es[]=$row['e'];
}
foreach($as as $x)
{
  $name=$x;
}....................and so on
```

i have checked and debuged in many ways.what i noticed **the script is not executing after while loop.**

Comment: as[], ... what are those?

Comment: Shouldn't `as[]`, `bs[]` etc have a $ if they're variables?

Comment: selecting all the values of `a` column into `as[]` array

Comment: that's the mistake typing here..am sorry..am editing it...this is not the issue

Comment: I mean if they're variables/arrays, they should be prefixed with "$". Otherwise, this is a syntax error, which might output an error, or outputs a blank page.

Comment: in my actual code i have written all those `$`..it was a mistake while typing in this forum

Comment: ok, how do you know that the script stops after while loop? can you add `echo 'before while';` before while and `echo 'after while';` inside while loop

Comment: that's what i have done..i have checked that way..i have echoed `before while loop starts` and echoed `after while loop ends` .....it never reaches to `after...........`

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to write $ before variables:

```
$as[]=$row['a'];
^------------
bs[]=$row['b'];
cs[]=$row['c'];
ds[]=$row['d'];
es[]=$row['e'];
```

Comment: this is not the issue...it was mistake while typing here...in my actual one i have written these $s

Answer (score 0):

What about using [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)? Also, use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for $as[] and all the arrays you got and paste the output here so we get a clearer idea of what the issue exactly is.

Comment: didn't understand..can u please describe..how and where i shoul use these

Comment: Right before the `foreach` statement, `print_r($as)` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\wbut\forum\wall.html.php on line 161

Comment: If you've wrote `print_r($as[])`, change it to just `print_r($as)`.

Comment: Use these lines to output errors. Write them at the beginning of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: i have tried all kind of debugging...most surprisingly no error displayed

Comment: If you're correct, print_r must give an output. Otherwise, double-check that the two lines I've given you are included in your script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717328/scriptwhile-loop-stops-and-no-ouputs-when-multiple-columns-are-selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell what print_r() function is printing so that we can identify the problem.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$as[]=$row['a'];
$bs[]=$row['b'];
$cs[]=$row['c'];
$ds[]=$row['d'];
$es[]=$row['e'];
}
print_r($as);
foreach($as as $x)
{
  $name=$x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the brackets from `$as[]`, the result of `$row['a']` will not be an array.

And that's the reason the `foreach` is not working, you're not getting an array back.

If the resulting `$as` is empty, but there is something in your database, make sure the rownames are valid.
Use `$row[0]` instead of `$row['A']`.

Debug your code using `print_r($row)` to the see the contents of the results.